# Sqlite3 database rails how to remove all records from command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am using ruby on rails and have my database setup as follows in the yaml file.

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I go to sqlite command line using sqlite3 from command prompt. I run the following command.

.databases and it does not return me the development.sqlite3 database. How can I see my own database and how can I query and remove records using sqlite command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call sqlite3 with the database as parameter

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
```